# php script is not able to verify data using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login form and i know how to submit data for verifying from database using submit button  but i want to submit my data using anchor tag and it must be verified using php, what i did is as follows and it's not working :

**index.php**

```
<form class="sign-form" action="login_process.php" method="post" id="lg" name="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="text">
                <input type="email"  name="email"/>
            </span>
            <span class="text">
                <input type="password"  name="pwd"/>
            </span>
            <input type="submit" value="Go" class="submit" name="submit" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="check-1">Remember me</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check-1" />
            <a href="chngpwd.html">Forgot your password?</a>

            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['loginFailed']) && !empty($_GET['loginFailed'])) {
                    $msg=$_GET['loginFailed'];
                    echo $msg;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="action_btns">
    <div class="one_half">
        <a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a>
        </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('lg').submit()" class="btn btn_red" name="submit">login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**login_process.php**

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
        $password=md5($pwd);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `registration` where Email='$email' AND Password='$password'";
        $van=mysqli_query($var,$sql);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($van);

        if ($count==1) {
            echo"hello";
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header("location: login_success.php");
        } else {
            header("location:index.php?loginFailed=wrong password or email");
        }   

        mysqli_close($var);
    }
?>
```

Comment: try `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('lg').submit()" class="btn btn_red" name="submit">Register</a>` since your form is `lg`, not `lgss`.

Comment: oh!! that's not an issue that is just becacuse of pressing ctrl+s a no of times

Comment: not sure whether it's a typo.You miss a `"` after `onclick="document.getElementById('lgss').submit()`

Comment: it's not an issue it's an error while posting

Comment: Can you update your question to what it does look like? Posting code with a typo is not good.#

Comment: i didn't type it i just paste itinto another row file then press ctrl+s then it occurs

Comment: So either your `form`s `id` is `lg` and you need to change your selector, or it is a typo and you need to update your question!

Comment: i have updated it please bring to me a solution

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to use an anchor to submit the form instead of a button. Several solutions exists for that, but let me say to you that using an anchor to submit a form requires the use of JavaScript to hook up the event. It's not safe in that if a user has JavaScript disabled, you won't be able to submit the form. It's better if you make a submit button looks like an anchor, like following:

```
<input type="submit" class="submitAnchor" value="Submit">
```

With this minimal style declaration:

```
.submitAnchor {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

Now, if you do really insist on using an anchor, you can e.g:

**1**.Event forwarding, activate the button submit event click when the anchor event click is activated:

```
<form name="form_lg" action="login_process.php" method="post" class="sign-form">
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" class="submit">
  <a href="#" onclick="form_lg['submit'].click()" class="btn btn_red">
     Register
  </a>
```

---

**2**.In case you don't want to forward events, you can e.g add a hidden input to store actions, like submit, back, etc. Then, you can catch the action value in the `login_process.php` file:

```
<form name="form_lg" action="login_process.php" method="post" class="sign-form">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
  <a href="javascript:form_lg.submit()" onclick="form_lg['action'].value='submit'"
     class="btn btn_red">Register</a>
```

In this case, you should change this line in `login_process.php` file. Instead of:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Do this:

```
if($_POST['action']=='submit') {
```

Hope it's helpful!

Comment: yeah now it's jumping on page login_process.php but it does not satisfy ` if(isset($_POST['submit']))`this condition and still i am getting a blank page instead of my login_success.php

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution much easier. But if you stick with the first solution let me know, and I give a trick.

Comment: now ur using an input type i want to submit without using input type i want to submit it using anchor tag

Comment: See the cause in the updated answer. I've also give you 2 tricks you can use in case you want to use an anchor. If you got stuck in some step, or if you need to understand something, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of the controls.
Having a control named submit in your form is overriding form.submit();

The error in the browser console is that .submit() is not a function.

So please, just change the name of the submit button with something else and it is working good.

```
<form class="sign-form" action="login_process.php" method="post" id="lg" name="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="text">
                <input type="email"  name="email"/>
            </span>
            <span class="text">
                <input type="password"  name="pwd"/>
            </span>
            <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" class="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="check-1">Remember me</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check-1" />
            <a href="chngpwd.html">Forgot your password?</a>

            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['loginFailed']) && !empty($_GET['loginFailed'])) {
                    $msg=$_GET['loginFailed'];
                    echo $msg;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="action_btns">
    <div class="one_half">
        <a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a>
        </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click()" class="btn btn_red" name="submit">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah now it's jumping on page login_process.php but it does not satisfy ` if(isset($_POST['submit']))`this condition and still i am getting a blank page instead of my login_success.php

Comment: I told you already, you are not getting any $_POST['submit'] because you didn't press any button. Check for other variable or you have to press your button and because submit is not more a input name. So just change condition with other check, like isset($_POST['email'])

Comment: or write var_dump($_POST); and check one time what you are receiving from your form.

Comment: i removed submit button and then named anchor tag submit and when i click on anchor ,i jump on login_process.php but it's balnk

Comment: No the anchor tag is not a in input. If you want to have at anycost the $_POST["submit"] in your php look at my updated answer